# Tiles 3 List attributes not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm facing several problems with my spring MVC project and tiles 3, and one of the main problems is with list attributes. What I'm trying to make is create a generic tiles definition using an `OptionsRenderer`, like in [the ultimate view article](http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/4/) (there is a mistake in the article, since the lit attribute is defined outside the definition, which is wrong). When I create some attributes with an `${options[myoptions]}` expression, I always get an `IllegalStateException` in my template JSP because a list attribute with the name `myoptions` is missing, even though I defined this list attribute. My code is as follows:

### tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="WILDCARD:*/*" template="/WEB-INF/view/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="meta" value="/WEB-INF/view/${options[folder]}/meta.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/${options[folder]}/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/${options[folder]}/{2}.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/${options[folder]}/footer.jsp" />

        <put-list-attribute name="folder">
            <add-list-attribute>
                <add-attribute value="{1}" />
                <add-attribute value="common" />
            </add-list-attribute>
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

### template.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
    contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>${dynamicTitle} - <fmt:message key="common.siteName" /></title>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="meta" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried several solutions with no result. My trials were as follows:
1. Use `<tiles:importAttribute name="folder"/>` in my JSP. Absolutely no difference
2. Use `<tiles:insertAttribute name="folder"/>` in my JSP. I got an exception since attribute was not a string.
3. Define attribute in JSP using `<tiles:putListAttribute name="folder">FULL_DEFINITION_HERE</tiles:putListAttribute>` no difference at all.

I've referred to the article mentioned above, and [tiles documentation](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/index.html) specifically the [OptionsRenderer documentation](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/apidocs/org/apache/tiles/extras/renderer/OptionsRenderer.html) with no use. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I believe that this is not related to spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I also wasn't able to use the OptionsRender, but liked the idea of being able to choose my templates in a directory hierarchy. So I wrote my own Renderer which seems to function quite well. I've implemented the path syntax "[CHOICE_1|CHOICE_2|...|CHOICE_n]", which selects the first choice which results in a valid path. An example would be:

```
  <definition name="main/*/*" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout_main.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="top" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/[{1}/{2}|{1}|common]/top.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/[{1}/{2}|{1}|common]/content.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/[{1}/{2}|{1}|common]/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
```

My Renderer implementation should also be able to replace several occurences of the choice pattern. The OptionsRender seems to not handle this case.

Here is the implementation of the Renderer. It has to be integrated into Apache Tiles like described in the [ultimate view article](http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/4/). Perhaps someone from Apache Tiles integrates it in the offical release. :-)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.tiles.request.Request;
import org.apache.tiles.request.render.Renderer;

public final class ChoiceRenderer implements Renderer {

    private static final Pattern CHOICE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");

    private final Renderer renderer;

    public ChoiceRenderer(Renderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRenderable(String path, Request request) {
        // only the overall format is checked, so no extra handling here
        return this.renderer.isRenderable(path, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(String path, Request request) throws IOException {
        Matcher matcher = CHOICE_PATTERN.matcher(path);
        List<String[]> groups = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "{[" + groups.size() + "]}");
            groups.add(matcher.group(1).split("\\|"));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        if (groups.isEmpty()) {
            this.renderer.render(path, request);
        } else {
            backtrackPaths(sb.toString(), request, groups, 0);
        }
    }

    private String backtrackPaths(String pathPattern, Request request, List<String[]> groups, int depth)
            throws IOException {
        String matchPath = null;
        String[] parts = groups.get(depth);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
            String path = pathPattern.replace("{[" + depth + "]}", parts[i]);
            if (depth == groups.size() - 1) {
                if (isPathValid(path, request)) {
                    this.renderer.render(path, request);
                    matchPath = path;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                matchPath = backtrackPaths(path, request, groups, depth + 1);
            }
        }
        return matchPath;
    }

    // TODO should we use caching here?
    private boolean isPathValid(String path, Request request) {
        boolean rtn = false;
        // apparently the corresponding Renderer method seems to check the
        // path's format only
        if (this.renderer.isRenderable(path, request)) {
            try {
                rtn = request.getApplicationContext().getResource(path) != null;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO the javadoc states that null will be returned, but
                // instead of it an exception is thrown.
                // Seems to be a bug?!
                boolean throwException = true;
                if (e.getCause() instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                    FileNotFoundException fex = (FileNotFoundException) e.getCause();
                    throwException = fex.getMessage().indexOf(path) == -1;
                }
                if (throwException) {
                    // seems to be a different reason as our searched path
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance you're still interested in trying OptionsRenderer again?
if there's functionality here that you'd like to add do submit a patch (via a jira issue) to us! https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `$` from `${options`.